# libharu — кириллица не отображается вменяемо

Tags: c, pdf

Ну собственно. Выводится вот так —›Ñ‚—¾ Ñ—¿—‚Ñ—¾—” —‡—¾Ñ€Ñˆ—”—¾—†.

Код:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include "hpdf.h"

jmp_buf env;

#ifdef HPDF_DLL
void  __stdcall
#else
void
#endif
error_handler (HPDF_STATUS   error_no,
               HPDF_STATUS   detail_no,
               void         *user_data)
{
    printf ("ERROR: error_no=%04X, detail_no=%u\n", (HPDF_UINT)error_no,
                (HPDF_UINT)detail_no);
    longjmp(env, 1);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *page_title = "LINNAEUS 0.0.1";
    HPDF_Doc  pdf;
    char fname[256];
    HPDF_Page page;
    HPDF_Font def_font;
    HPDF_REAL height;
    HPDF_REAL width;

    const char *detail_font_name;

    HPDF_REAL tw;

    strcpy (fname, "plants");
    strcat (fname, ".pdf");

    pdf = HPDF_New (error_handler, NULL);

    detail_font_name = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile (pdf, "Courier.ttf", HPDF_FALSE);
    
    if (!pdf) {
        printf ("error: cannot create PdfDoc object\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (setjmp(env)) {
        HPDF_Free (pdf);
        return 1;
    }

    /* Add a new page object. */
    page = HPDF_AddPage (pdf);

    height = HPDF_Page_GetHeight (page);
    width = HPDF_Page_GetWidth (page);

    /* Print the title of the page (with positioning center). */
    def_font = HPDF_GetFont (pdf, detail_font_name, NULL);
    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize (page, def_font, 12);

    tw = HPDF_Page_TextWidth (page, page_title);
    HPDF_Page_BeginText (page);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, (width - tw) / 50, height - 20, page_title);
    HPDF_Page_EndText (page);

    /* output subtitle. */
    HPDF_Page_BeginText (page);
    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize (page, def_font, 12);
    HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, 10, height - 40, "16.12.1983");
    HPDF_Page_EndText (page);

    HPDF_Page_BeginText (page);
    HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos (page, 10, height - 105);
    
    const char* samp_text = "Это список горшков";

    /* print a label of text */
    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize (page, def_font, 12);
    HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos (page, 0, -18);

    /* print a sample text. */
    HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, samp_text);
    HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, HPDF_Font_GetEncodingName (detail_font));
    HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos (page, 0, -20);

    HPDF_Page_EndText (page);

    HPDF_SaveToFile (pdf, fname);

    /* clean up */
    HPDF_Free (pdf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136417/have-to-embed-fonts-when-using-utf-8-in-libharu

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, вот так: detail_font_name = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile (pdf, "Courier.ttf", HPDF_FALSE); но, всё по-прежнему. Может быть есть специфика использования этого? Какая-то конструкция? Я обновил код в вопросе.

Comment: Шрифт не самое главное. В твоём коде нет ни одного упоминания UTF-8 или какой-то другой кодировки. `const char* samp_text = "Это список горшков"` создаёт однобайтовые символы, у них нет кодировки, поэтому `Э` будет отрисовываться как `Ý`, если эту строку будут отрисовывать как UTF-8

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, а как решить в моём случае? У меня данные в результате будут из sqlite, сейчас просто тестирую, знакомлюсь, как оно вообще себя поведёт.

Comment: sqllite можно и нужно настроить на работу с UTF-8.

Comment: А для "просто тестирования" я тебе дал ссылку, где HPDF настраивается на работу с UTF-8. Ты там кроме шрифта не увидел ничего?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, спасибо! Вопрос снят :)